# SQL Server 2008: trying to export my data to xls file and data not displaying in rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql query wich imports Data from a csv file and then matches that data with records on my database to make sure that records do exist, when thats done It then exports the file to an xls file, when It export to the file the result set all outputs in a single line insted of rows like It imported. eg. imported rows 10, matched 7. exported rows 1 intead of 7:

DROP TABLE CSVdataRaw,#FileList,#TmpID/*#Failures,#Success,*/ --,#ReverseFile

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.tables WHERE name = 'CSVdataRaw')
    BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE CSVdataRaw
    (     
    CellNumber varchar(12),
    SMS_MSG varchar(250)

    )
    END

    Create Table #FileList ( 
    SMSFilename Varchar(512))


    Declare @Path varchar(256) = 'dir C:\FileImport\Inbox\'
    Declare @Command varchar(1024) =  @Path+' /A-D  /B' 
    --PRINT @Command

    Insert #FileList 
    Exec Master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
    delete #FileList where  SMSFilename is Null 

    Declare @File varchar (255) = 
    ( SELECT top 1 * FROM #FileList
    where SMSFilename like 'SMS%') 
    print @File

    Declare @SMSFilename Varchar (255)
    Set @SMSFilename = 'C:\FileImport\Inbox\'
    Set @SMSFilename = @SMSFilename + @File -- + ''''


    declare @BulkInsert varchar(MAX); 
    set @BulkInsert = 'BULK INSERT [CSVdataRaw] 
    From ' + char(39) + @SMSFilename +char(39)+
    ' With (ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', Firstrow = 1)'
    --print @BulkInsert

    exec(@BulkInsert)

    ALTER TABLE CSVdataRaw ADD ID INT IDENTITY
    GO


    alter table CSVDataRaw add Matterno Varchar (50) 
    GO
    update CSVDataRaw set Matterno = (SELECT TOP 1 H_MID FROM History WHERE H_PhoneNumber = CSVDataRaw.CellNumber)
    GO

    alter table CSVDataRaw add H_Description varchar(50) 
    GO
    update CSVdataRaw set H_Description = (select top 1 H_IDX from History with (nolock) where H_Description = CSVdataRaw.SMS_MSG) 
    GO

    delete from CSVDataRaw where Matterno is null

    CREATE TABLE #TmpID
    (
      ID INT,
      Note VARCHAR(255)
    )

    DECLARE @Line varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @FileName varchar(255)
    DECLARE @Row int

    --INSERT HEADER
    SET @FileName = 'C:\FileImport\SMS_History_' + replace(replace(replace(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),120),' ',''),'-',''),':','')  + '.xls'
    SET @Line = 'Profile=0,Product=0,Client=0,ImportType=20,Delimiter= ,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

    DELETE #TmpID

    Insert into #TmpID (ID, Note)
    select CellNumber, SMS_MSG
    from CSVDataRaw


    SELECT @Line = @Line + Note FROM #TmpID
    --print @Line
    EXEC dbo.uspWriteToFile @FileName, @Line
    --print @Line
    DROP TABLE CSVdataRaw,#TmpID,#FileList

    Create Table #FileList ( 
    SMSFilename Varchar(512))
    Declare @Path varchar(256) = 'dir C:\FileImport\Inbox\'
    Declare @Command varchar(1024) =  @Path+' /A-D  /B' 
    Insert #FileList 
    Exec Master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
    delete #FileList where  SMSFilename is Null 

    Declare @File varchar (255) = 
    (SELECT top 1 * FROM #FileList
    where SMSFilename like 'SMS%') 
    print @File

    Declare @SMSFilename Varchar (255)
    Set @SMSFilename = 'move /y C:\FileImport\Inbox\ C:\FileImport\Archive\' --Here you are setting a variable
    Set @SMSFilename = @SMSFilename + @File  + ''''

    exec xp_cmdshell 'move /y C:\FileImport\Inbox\ C:\FileImport\Archive' --This part you are actually MOVING the file

    DROP TABLE #FileList
```

Comment: It strikes me that Integration Services might be a better tool for this rather than trying to cobble something together with T-SQL and `xp_cmdshell` calls

Comment: HI, Haven't used Intergration services yet. I will look into it though. Thanks.

Comment: It does have a bit of a learning curve to it, so if you do decide to go this route, don't expect to have the whole lot sorted out in a matter of minutes